# UICollectionView cellForItemAt: won't be called while layoutAttributesForElements are returning values

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a bit complex `UICollectionView` with my custom `UICollectionViewLayout`.
I added a pinch gesture behavior onto it and adjust the layout according to that result. 
It's basically working pretty well, the cells are resized and repositioned properly in normal cases.

But when it comes to a particular condition the cells disappear and never appear again.
So far I'm unable to clarify the condition, but it happens often when you pinched the view to a smaller size.

The issue is, `layoutAttributesForElements` in my collection view layout is called (of course this also implies that `numberOfCells:inSection` is called as well) and it's returning reasonable cell geometry, but actual cell generation (`cellForItemAt:`) won't be called.

Before jumping into the code(as it's a bit too long and complicated) I want to ask you guys if any of you have had the same kind of situation. 
Below is the summary of what's happening and what I see so far.

- It's **not that always happening**. It happens only after pinching and reached to a certain condition. So this is not a basic kind of how-to-use-UICollectionView issue.
- Even when it happens **`layoutAttributesForElements` keeps being called** (as you keep pinching)
- **The layout attributes don't have crazy values** like zero size or position of far out of view range. They all have the position attributes that fit into the collection view's content size.
- **Collection view claims the proper content view size** (at least as reported on the debugger.)
- When it happens you cannot see any cells in the view hierarchy in the View Debugger. Meaning, it's not zero sized or clear colored but **cells themselves are gone**. This corresponds to the fact that cellForItemAt: is not called.
- After it happened you cannot see the cells anymore even you pinch the screen back to the original scale.

Any information is appreciated.  Thanks!

## EDIT

My collection view layout is like this. This project is a musical sequencer and the collection view is showing your musical notes in piano roll style.

```
//
//  YMPianoRollLayout.swift
//
import UIKit

class YMPianoRollLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    let notes : Array<CGPoint> = []

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!;
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize : CGSize {

        let cv = self.collectionView as! YMPianoRollCollectionView
        let screenInfo = cv.pianoRollViewController.screenInfo        
        let totalSize = screenInfo.collectionViewContentsSize();

        print("contentSize = \(totalSize)")

        return totalSize;
    }    

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        // "screenInfo" keeps the user specified view parameters including the scale ratio by the pinch gesture
        let cv = self.collectionView as! YMPianoRollCollectionView;
        let pianoRoll = cv.pianoRollViewController;

        // Check which musical note can be included in the view rect
        let indexArray: Array<Int> = pianoRoll!.getNoteIndexes(inRect:rect, useOnlyStartTime: false);

        var retArray : [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

        for i in indexArray {
            if let _ = pianoRoll?.pattern.eventSequence[i] as? YMPatternEventNoteOn {
                retArray.append( self.layoutAttributesForPatternEventInfo(i) )
            }
        }

        // This always reports non-zero count. Also checked the positions of each array members 
        // by breaking here and they all had proper size and positions
        print("retArray count = \(retArray.count)"); 

        return retArray
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let i = Int((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
        return self.layoutAttributesForPatternEventInfo(i)
    }

    //
    // This is my specific func to convert the musical time-pitch into the view geometory
    //
    func layoutAttributesForPatternEventInfo(_ index: Int) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes!{
        let cv = self.collectionView as! YMPianoRollCollectionView

        // "screenInfo" keeps the user specified view parameters including the scale ratio by the pinch gesture
        let screenInfo = cv.pianoRollViewController.screenInfo 

        // Retrieve musical event
        let event = cv.pianoRollViewController.pattern.eventSequence[index]        

        let index = IndexPath(row:index, section: 0)        
        let newAttr = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith:index)

        var frame : CGRect!

        if let e = event as? YMPatternEventNoteOn {
            let noteNo = e.noteNo;
            let origin = YMMusicalValuePoint(time:event.time, noteNumber:noteNo);
            let size = YMMusicalValueSize(timeLength:e.duration, numberOfNotes: 1);

            // Actual size calculation is done in my "screenInfo" class.
            frame = screenInfo.getPhysicalRange(YMMusicalValueRange(origin:origin, size:size));
        } else {
            frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0);
        }

        newAttr.frame = frame;
        newAttr.zIndex = 1;

        return newAttr
    }

    //
    // For checking the bounds
    //
    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        print("BBB newBounds = \(newBounds)") 
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an interesting problem...

More info on your custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass (i.e. the code) would be useful but I can offer an overview of how `UICollectionView` typically updates visible content in response to bounds changes (i.e. content offset, rotation) and `invalidateLayout` calls.

When `invalidateLayout` fires the internal attributes cache is cleared signaling the need to ask the layout on the next `layoutSubviews` pass what should be visible. Conversely, if the layout is **not** invalidated and the attributes are known in the cache the layout will not be asked.

The magic all happens when the current CA transaction commits and `UICollectionView`'s `layoutSubviews` is invoked. At this point, a diff between what was last known to be on screen and what should now be on screen is computed according the current "visible bounds" (effectively the scroll view's bounds which includes the offset into the layout).

Cells no longer visible in the new visible bounds will be returned to the reuse queue and newly appearing cells (as per the layout) will be constructed and existing items (that have changed) will be updated with their new attributes.

Based on your description, it sounds like when the next `layoutSubviews` fires the queried attributes (possibly from the cache!) aren't returning anything for the new visible bounds therefore nothing "new" appears -- along with the existing items disappearing...

A few things to investigate might include:

1. Is your gesture causing your custom layout to invalidate? If not, it probably should so the `UICollectionView` knows to not trust it's internal attributes cache and always ask the layout for new attributes during the "diffing" process.
2. How is the bounds of the collection changing during the pinch gesture?
   This directly affects the diff since it will use this visible bounds to determine what should be displayed next.
3. How does your layout respond to `shouldInvalidateForBoundsChange:`?
   Most layouts only invalidate when the extents (e.g. rotation) change, so the `UICollectionView` will normally rely on it's cached attributes when performing the diff. In your case if you are tweaking the bounds during the gesture, you'll want to unconditionally return YES here.
4. When you get into this wonky state, you might try pausing into the debugger e.g.

   ```
   po [[cv collectionViewLayout] invalidateLayout] 
   po [cv setNeedsLayout] 
   po [cv layoutIfNeeded]
   ```

...and resume. Has everything re-appeared?

If so, it sounds like the layout isn't being invalidated under certain circumstances and the attributes being returned are indeed reasonable.

If not, ping the layout and see what if it is reporting as visible is reasonable via:

```
po [[cv collectionViewLayout] layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:cv.bounds]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I'll check my code according to  your checkpoints.

Comment: I've checked the code and it's invalidating the layout as you pinch.  But I've found that shouldInvalidateForBoundsChange: is called but it always  reports the same width and hight.  And I also found that collectionViewContentSize are called and it returns different values according to the pinching result.

Comment: I was a bit confused about "bounds" but now I'm clear.  bounds' size should remain the same because it corresponds to the viewed area in the content, right?

Understanding in this way, I rechecked the bounds and content size, to have found that cells disappear when bounds' bottom edge goes out of the content size.  It is kind of understandable that something goes wrong with this condition because it might be an unexpected situation, but it's still weird that it won't go back to the normal status even after pinch or scroll it back.

Comment: Aha! sounds like you found the root cause!  So, the layout's attributes need to be within the layout's `collectionViewContentSize` for them to have meaning to the `UICollectionView`. Since they don't, the cells disappear.  If you update your layout to recompute the `collectionViewContentSize` when your layout invalidation occurs (in `prepareLayout()`) things should start working a bit better....

Comment: Hmm..  I don't think this is the very cause of the issue.  Because it's pretty likely that the bounds goes out of the content size when the collection view allows bouncing, and actually the cells didn't disappear when I scrolled beyond the border  (and it bounced back as expected, to prove that content size was just as I've specified).

Comment: Although I don't know what's really happening internally but I've just implemented a prevention from being out of content-size in pinching behavior, and now the issue has gone.  Thank you for the valuable hints, @breeno !